# Как убрать автоматический перенос курсора в консоли?

Tags: python, python-3.x, вывод, print

```
for k in range(2):
    print("Hello")

Hello
Hello
```

А я хочу:

```
for k in range(2):
    print("Hello ")

Hello Hello
```

Не подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for _ in range(3):
    print('Hello', end=' ')    
print()
```

выведет:

```
Hello Hello Hello
```

У [print()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print) есть необязательный параметр `end`, со значением по умолчанию - перенос строки...

---

От последнего принта можно избавиться, добавив параметр flush:

```
for _ in range(3):
    print('Hello', end=' ', flush=True)
```

```
Hello Hello Hello
```

сработает для python от 3.3 и выше

Comment: в питоне что-ле нет принта без /n ?

Comment: @dresser По умолчанию в `print` параметр `end='\n'`, так что только через изменение параметра `end=`